# using rbind to combine all data sets the names of all data set start with common characters

Tags: r

I want to combine all rows of different data sets. The names of all data sets starts with test. All data sets have same number of observations. I know i can combine it by using rbind(). But typing the names of every data set will take a lot of time. Suggest me some better approach.

```
rbind(test1,test2,test3,test4)
```

Comment: Can you save your data sets in a list? Rather than saving them as objects individually?

Comment: If you save your data sets in a list eg: test[[1]],test[[2]] etc. then you can use functions like `data.table::rbindlist()` or `dplyr::bind_rows()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try first obtaining a vector of all matching objects using `ls()` with the pattern `^test`:

```
dfs <- lapply(ls(pattern="^test"), function(x) get(x))
result <- rbindlist(dfs)
```

I am taking the suggestion by @Rohit to use `rbindlist` to make our lives easier to `rbind` together a list of data frames.

Comment: I have always found ```bind_rows``` to be faster than ```rbindlist```.

Comment: if there are many elements to put in a list you need the `mget` eg `mget(ls(pattern = "^test"))`

Answer (score 1):

Second line of above code will work only if data sets are in data.table form or data frame form. IF data sets are in xts/zoo format then one  have to make slight improvement use do.call() function.

```
## First make a list of all your data sets as suggested above
list_xts <- lapply(ls(pattern="^test"), function(x) get(x))
## then use do call and rbind()
xts_results<-do.call(rbind,list_xts)
```